# sql query to get bi-weekly data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBnrX.png)I want to know the start bi-week date and end bi-week date.
means i want to get bi-weekly data from the below table structure.

```sql
create table #temp(
    EmployeeID int,
    TEDate datetime,
    EmpFNamenvarchar(100),
    EmpLName nvarchar(100)
)
go

insert into #temp (EmployeeID ,EmpFName,EmpLName,TEDate) 
Select 2019,'roz','Ahmad','2019-04-23' 
union all 
Select 2019,'roz','Ahmad','2019-04-17' 
union all 
Select 2019,'roz','Ahmad','2019-04-29' 

select * from #temp
```

How to do it? I have used below approach but still getting wrong results at the end.

```sql
Select *,
       DATEADD(WEEK, DATEPART(wk, TEDate), 
       DATEADD(YEAR, year(TEDate) - 1900, 0)) - 4 - DATEPART(DW, DATEADD(WEEK, DATEPART(wk, TEDate), 
       DATEADD(YEAR, year(TEDate) - 1900, 0)) - 4) + 1 AS [BiWEEK_START],
       DATEADD(WEEK, DATEPART(wk, TEDate), 
       DATEADD(YEAR, year(TEDate) - 1900, 0)) - 4 - DATEPART(DW, DATEADD(WEEK, DATEPART(wk, TEDate), 
       DATEADD(YEAR, year(TEDate) - 1900, 0)) - 4) + 14 AS [BiWEEK_END] 
from #temp
```

Desired results:

```
4/17/2019
4/14/2019
4/27/2019
4/22/2019
4/14/2019
4/27/2019
4/23/2019
4/14/2019
4/27/2019
4/29/2019
4/28/2019
5/11/2019
5/3/2019
4/28/2019
5/11/2019
5/6/2019
4/28/2019
5/11/2019
5/8/2019
4/28/2019
5/11/2019
5/13/2019
5/12/2019
5/25/2019
```

Comment: When does the bi-weekly start at the beginning of the year?  Which day of the week (Saturday, Sunday, Monday)?

Comment: Break statement into smaller pieces so you can get value of each piece.  What value is each function returning?

Comment: Can you please post the some sample data and expected output?

Comment: We need to calculate start of tedate as start week. then onwards combine 2 weeks and show the data.We can specify it from monday

Comment: It's great you've posted sample data as DDL+DML, but what would make this question truly awesome is if you could also add your desired results.

Comment: 4/17/2019  Start Date= 4/14/2019       END Date=4/27/2019
4/22/2019  Start Date= 4/14/2019       END Date=4/27/2019
4/23/2019 Start Date=  4/14/2019 END Date=4/27/2019
4/29/2019 Start Date=  4/28/2019 END Date=5/11/2019
5/3/2019         Start Date= 4/28/2019 END Date=5/11/2019
5/6/2019         Start Date=        4/28/2019 END Date=5/11/2019
5/8/2019     Start Date=      4/28/2019 END Date=5/11/2019
5/13/2019 Start Date=        5/12/2019 END Date=5/25/2019

Comment: Ok, I get it. Question is, how do you tell for a specific date whether it's in the first week or the second week?

Comment: my output should be this {link} (https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBnrX.png)

Comment: Yep, I get what the output should be, but can you tell by looking at a single date which bi_week it belongs to without looking at the table of bi_weeks?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here are two solutions. The problem is, you have to be able to tell which bi week a TEDate belongs to just by looking at the TEDate, otherwise you have to define either a list of the bi weeks or tell your query where to start. For the second query you should be able to put in any bi week start date and it should still work.

```
DECLARE @bi_weeks TABLE
(
StartDate DATE,
EndDate DATE
);

INSERT INTO @bi_weeks VALUES
('20190317','20190330'),
('20190331','20190413'),
('20190414','20190427'),
('20190428','20190511'),
('20190512','20190525');


DECLARE @emp_data TABLE
(
    EmployeeID INT,
    TEDate DATETIME,
    EmpFName NVARCHAR(100),
    EmpLName NVARCHAR(100)
);


INSERT INTO @emp_data (EmployeeID ,EmpFName,EmpLName,TEDate) VALUES
(2019,'roz','Ahmad','2019-03-20'),
(2019,'roz','Ahmad','2019-04-01'),
(2019,'roz','Ahmad','2019-04-13'),
(2019,'roz','Ahmad','2019-04-23'),
(2019,'roz','Ahmad','2019-04-17'),
(2019,'roz','Ahmad','2019-04-29');

--This is the first way where we join to a list of known bi week start and end dates
SELECT ed.*, bw.*
FROM @emp_data ed
LEFT JOIN @bi_weeks bw ON ed.TEDate BETWEEN bw.StartDate AND bw.EndDate
ORDER BY 2


--This is the second way where we tell our query a known start date and then use it to
--calculate the rest of the start and end dates.
DECLARE @initial_bi_week_start_date DATE = '20190414';

With empdataCTE AS
(
SELECT *,
[initial_bi_week_start_date] = @initial_bi_week_start_date ,
[bi_week_start] = 
DATEADD(DAY,
            (DATEDIFF(DAY, @initial_bi_week_start_date, TEDate) / 14 +
                    IIF(TEDate < @initial_bi_week_start_date, 1, 0) * -1) * 14,
            @initial_bi_week_start_date)

FROM @emp_data ed
)

SELECT *, DATEADD(DAY, 13, [bi_week_start]) [bi_week_end] 
FROM empdataCTE;
```